# CSS Change Border Color on Hover

Tags: css

I'm using the following CSS code to create a box around some content/links:

```css
.box {
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;  
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 40px; 
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

I want to make it so that when the mouse cursor hovers over the box, the black border color changes to purple.

Comment: `.box:hover { border-color: purple; }`

Comment: .box:hover { new css code here }

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `:hover` psuedo selector:

```
.box:hover {
   border-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and it looks like the person who did clearly explained why.  You didn't address the answer with a solution the OP is requesting.

Comment: No I know you didn't downvote me. I didn't post an answer. I'm asking why you were downvoted. 6 upvotes and 1 downvote. this is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure why.  This is basic CSS knowledge...how it could be incorrect is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy, just apply the selector :hover

```
.box:hover {
    border:5px solid #b217b4;
}
```

[JSFiddle Here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/CypmL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `color` instead of `border-color` which inherits the color of the border as well:

```
.box {
border:2px solid;
color: #000;
}

.box:hover {
color:purple;
}
```

See this **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/M62eX/1/)**.

Comment: The OP wants to change the border color, not text color. `border: 2px solid purple;`...

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M62eX/2/). This solution does work. However, if text is within the container, the text color changes too which the OP didn't ask for. You should either reset the border or change the border color...

Comment: @War10ck You should learn accepting alternative solutions! This is the whole point of SO. BTW I don't see in OP that the color is defined!

Comment: Define _"accepting alternative solutions"_. This creates an undesired consequence which the OP did not ask for. Therefore, it's not a solution.

Comment: This isn't an alternative solution, it's an incorrect solution.  The OP clearly states "border color", however your solution changes the font color.

Comment: @War10ck It's an alternative! The OP doesn't define a color for text. So, learn to accept more than one answers

Comment: alternative solution: .box { display:none; } :)

Comment: Correct. The OP doesn't define a color for text because that wasn't what the question asked for. I'm sorry if you disagree. If the OP doesn't care about text, then this is a suitable answer. However, without further knowledge of the OP's situation, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @otinanai - An alternative solution would solve the initial problem he's asking for (border-color) using a different method then what's been posted.  Your solution solves a completely different problem which means it cannot sufficiently act as a legitimate *alternative solution*.