# How to use mouseover to change border color of a css shape(circle)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve this circular navigation menu
example : http://www.jerseywater.je/water/index.html#page_0/

I have done almost all of it!
 the problem now is how to change a border of a css shape with mouseover function 
edit:
"that is when i hover some other shape the border color will change in the main circle"

```css
#circle {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #888888;    
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
    border: 4px solid #73AD21;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-60px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
    <p id="content">
        Blah Blah
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: [CSS :hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: `i hover some other shape the border color will change in the main circle` ?? You want to change border of some other element on hovering this circle?

Comment: the opposite while i hover some other object i want this circle to change border color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Change Border Color on Hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245247/css-change-border-color-on-hover)

Comment: Have a look at my answer and try it in codepen. Is that what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#circle" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $( this ).css("border","black solid 1px");
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).css("border","red solid 1px");
  });
});
```

Something like this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2kLpLw1) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#circle:hover {
  border-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what you may want to achieve:

http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/ZBBdBM

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main_circle"> Look</div>
  <div class="menu_items item1">Menu Item 1</div>
  <div class="menu_items item2">Menu Item 2</div>
  <div class="menu_items item3">Menu Item 3</div>
  <div class="menu_items item4">Menu Item 4</div>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.main_circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  background: blue;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main_circle:before {
  content: "";
  height: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.menu_items {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.item1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 250px;
}

.item2 {
  top: 260px;
  right: 20px;
}

.item3 {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 250px;
}

.item4 {
  top: 260px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

and js

```
var menuItems = $('.menu_items').length;
var step = 360 / menuItems;

$('.menu_items').on('mouseover' , function(){
  var classList = $(this).attr('class');
  var identifier = classList.split(' ')[1].substr(4,1);

  var calc = (parseInt(identifier) - 1) * step;
  var transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(' + calc + 'deg)';
  console.log(transform);
  $('.main_circle').css('transform', transform);
});
```

if you increase the number of menu-items, reposition them with css and the js will still work. Name the classes as I did with item#(number) and it should work. Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

In the css use `:hover` eg:

```
#circle:hover {
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

More details can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp