# How to have border color change on image hover/mousover?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know how to add a border to images, but how do I change the color of the border on image hover/mouseover, I would like to to this to multiple images on the same page, so far I have failed to find a plugin that does this.

I spent like 5 hours looking for a plugin to do this, feel my pain!!!

Basically, I want an image to do what a button does. When user hovers the mouse over the button the color of the border changes.

Comment: `img:hover { border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Change Border Color on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245247/css-change-border-color-on-hover)

Comment: How's my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44912759/7733026

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` psuedo selector:

```
img:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Also, if you want it to be like a button, consider these styles as well:

```
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
img:active {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
img:active {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
```

And using `box-shadow` is just as simple:

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px black;
}
img:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
```

and to make the image a bit bigger, use `transform: scale(1.1);`

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px black;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
img:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
```

Comment: nice, now how to I increase the image size just a tiny little bit on hover? So basically im making the image pop effect just a tiny bit

Answer (score 1):

You can get by using following css

```css
img {
  border:2px solid #000;
}
img:hover {
  border:2px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
```

With shadow hover effect

```css
img {
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #000;
}
img:hover {
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
```

Comment: instead of a border, how do i do a box shadow around the image on hover?

Comment: You can use by `box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;` instead of `border` property. check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use outline instead

```
.imgclass:hover {
   outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

This way you do not have any movements or corallations with other elements

Answer (score 0):

add 1px border with red color to all images on hover

```css
img:hover {
  border:1px solid #C04848;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<style>
  img:hover { 
     border: 1px solid black; 
  }
</style>
```

You can perform the same using pseudo class hover in css

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: inside style tag in head

Comment: I think you are a newbie, just add the entire style inside head tag

Comment: yep a newbie, i did but it changes image size on hover, how do i have like an outer border that changes in color on mouseover

Comment: Just have a predefined border of certain color and on hover change its color  in the above mentioned way

Comment: how do i do a box shadow on hover instead of a border?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` pseudoclass.

```
img
{
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}

img:hover
{
  border-color:red;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xo7wqvp/)

Comment: how do i do a box shadow on image hover instead of a border?

Comment: @tim There are some different options but the simplest may be `box-shadow`. [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3g4wppxy/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
.image_class:hover{ border:1px solid #0f0; }
```

here image_class is class on your img tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a border on hovering the element, then:

```
<style>
.nameofclass:hover {
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

The above CSS will apply a red border with 1px width. Change the `nameofclass` to name of the element e.g image/button you're trying to add effects on.

**NOTE:** The `<style>` tag is added within the `<head>` tag. Something like:

```
<head>
    <style>
    .nameofclass:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

I hope it helps, if you need help, feel free to ask.

**UPDATE:** Use the following code for adding box shadow!

`-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.91) ;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.91) ;`

Just copy paste it under the code I gave you before in this very answer.

Comment: yes, instead of a border, what is the code for a box shadow around the image on hover?